# How do you say "this article was originally published in German?

Tags: translation

How do you say "this article was originally published in German?

本文原載於德文

？

Comment: Your translation is right.

Comment: "初版以德文發表" or "原稿以德文發表" or simply "原稿為德文"

Answer (score 1):

This article was originally published in German.
这篇文章最初是以德语出版的。

Answer (score 1):

这篇文章最初以德文发布。
no sense  30 words walawala booboo

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:
「原文以德文發佈。」

原文

> The original passage

以

> was being

德文

> German

發佈

> Published

Answer (score 1):

本文章原以德文出版。

What you proposed actually mean "this article was originally published on (a magazine called) German".

Answer (score 0):

本文原文系德文。

You see, Chinese expression is relatively concise.

Comment: Perhaps something like "本文原為德文" or "原稿為德文"

Answer (score -1):

本文原稿(this article originally)为德语(in German)所著(published)。